# Change url based on drop down selection & text box value

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a very simple form. I'm trying to redirect the page based on dropdown value selected and value entered in the text box.

My form looks like this:
http://devilscircuit.com/new/test.html

It just has a select box, a text box & a submit button. I'm trying to redirect the page once user clicks on submit button.

I'm not very well versed with JavaScript.

Can someone help me with it?

My current JavaScript looks something like this:

```
<script>
function setURL(){
var dt_value = document.getElementById("dt_id").value;
var dt_value2 = document.getElementById("dt_id2").value;
var sjdurl =  "http://parshwatax.com/devilscircuit2/+dt_value2/index.php?     
controller=search&search_query="+dt_value;
window.location.href=(sjdurl);
}
</script>
```

HTML Is below:

```
<h4 class="title2">Search Your Picture</h4>
<label>Please Select an Event </label>
<select style="width:205px; margin-left:68px;" id="dt_id2"> 
<option value="shop1">GURGAON'14</option>
<option value="shop2">NOIDA'13</option>
<option value="shop3">LUDHIANA'12</option>
</select> </br>

<label for="dt_id">Please enter your BIB number </label>
<input type="Text" id="dt_id" maxlength="25" size="23" style="margin: 5px 21px;"/> </br>
                    <input type='button' onclick='setURL()' value='SUBMIT' style="margin: 10px 208px;">
```

Please help me fix the redirect. THanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple issues.  One is your "sjdurl" concatenation has a syntax error.  Should be

```
var sjdurl =  "http://parshwatax.com/devilscircuit2/"+dt_value2+"/index.php?     
controller=search&search_query="+dt_value;
```

Another issue is your retrieving the selected value of your "dt_id2" select field incorrectly. It should be like:

```
var dt_select = document.getElementById("dt_id2");
var dt_value2 = dt_select.options[dt_select.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: Ok, so my new version looks something like this. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: I realized my code had a typo. Changed "select" to "dt_select".